# How do I know who logged to what schema in HANA?

Tags: hana

How do I know who logged, when logged, how long `HANA` being used by user, to what schema user accessed in My `SAP HANA SPS 11`?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check "SYS"."AUDIT_LOG" and "SYS"."AUDIT_ACTIONS" system views?

Comment: Hi Erapler , thanks for reply, i did find AUDIT_LOG but not AUDIT_ACTIONS,

Comment: I have it on hana2sp03. You can find audit_actions (Provides information about all available audit actions) on System Views Reference document